# calling functions using lookup table in Backbone View isn't passing "this" (the view) to the function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a function in a Backbone View that gets called from an event. Different functions in the View get called based on a var called `selected`, so I made a lookup table to route the values of selected to functions in my view:

```
var cases = {
    'application' : this.choose_application,
    'device'      : this.choose_device,
    'log'         : this.choose_log,
    'process'     : this.choose_process,
    'server'      : this.choose_server,
    'network'     : this.choose_network
}
```

Then I call the function:

```
var func = cases[selected];
func();
```

When a function from the lookup table gets called (`this.choose_log`, for example), `this` in the `choose_log` function equals the Window object rather than the View.

As expected, if instead of using the lookup table, I simply call `this.choose_log()`, `this` in the `choose_log` function equals the View.

How can I pass make `this` equal the View within all of the functions in my lookup table? And more importantly, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I pass make this equal the View within all of the functions in my lookup table?

Use `cases[selected].call(this);` - see [docs for `call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

> And more importantly, why is this happening?

Because the value of the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) depends on how the function is called. In the "usual" case it does work as expected because you call the function *as a method* **on** the View instance.